# What is the equivalent of $ModuleNumber for DynamicModule

Tags: front-end, dynamic, scoping, implementation-details, undocumented

*Mathematica* provides access to `$ModuleNumber` which can be enormously useful.

Unfortunately I can't find the equivalent for `DynamicModule`.

I know such a parameter must exist for two reasons:

First, consider evaluating `DynamicModule[{A}, Dynamic[A]]` four times:

```
DynamicModule[{A}, Dynamic[A]]
=> FE`A$$4
DynamicModule[{A}, Dynamic[A]]
=> FE`A$$5
DynamicModule[{A}, Dynamic[A]]
=> FE`A$$6
DynamicModule[{A}, Dynamic[A]]
=> FE`A$$7
```

This incrementation suggests the existence of such a variable.

Secondly, looking at the internals of `DynamicModule` one finds references to a parameter `serialno_`, specifically in `` FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule ``

Using `UpValues` and print statements on like `` Refresh[FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule[a___],___]:>Print[{a}] ``
one finds that the second argument to `` FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule `` `(serialno_)` increments each time, but pulling back one step further to `` FrontEnd`SynchronousDynamicEvaluate[___,Refresh[FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule[a___],___],___] `` provides no information, as `` FrontEnd`SynchronousDynamicEvaluate `` does not directly provide a serial number and its DownValues give no hints for how to proceed.

Now, I also know that this parameter, whatever it is, is fundamentally a front end parameter, due to both looking at the evaluation chain and code of `DynamicModule` and because this function:

```
frontEndModule[varSpec_, body_]] :> 
Block[{Manipulate`Dump`$eDynamicModule = True}, 
DynamicModule[varSpec, body]
```

Behaves identically to the `DynamicModule` behavior seen above, except in both following the code and in watching the evaluation chain, none of the heavy module-machinery of `DynamicModule` is invoked.

Unfortunately after many hours of searching and testing I still do not know where to find this parameter, although I feel like I must be close with the `serialno_` argument to `FE'ExecuteInDynamicModule`.

I'm assuming the symbol will be in some front end context, because I've searched nearly exhaustively through the symbols of the various `Manipulate` and `Dynamic` contexts via a symbol-browser and an `OwnValues` based test to see which symbols (using string pattern `"*"`) are numeric did not reveal the answer, although I can confirm that it produced `$ModuleNumber`, as a sanity check.

Does anyone know where to find this?

Comment: Can I ask why do you need this? It seems that th `$xx` part will change anyway when you save/open the notebook with created DM.

Comment: About the context marker, take a look here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14/12

Comment: I doubt this is available as a kernel variable like `$ModuleNumber`, ``FE`*`` or ``FrontEnd`*`` symbols.  If it were, there should be some evidence in [LinkSnooper](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73621/4999) while watching dynamic module instantiation, but I don't see any.  Maybe you can query the FE to tell you the current number.

Comment: @Kuba It provides a clean and simple way to predictively assess what a `DynamicModule` will call a variable, which can be used in all the same ways as for `Module`

@ Michel E2 how would you suggest going about that? I've looked through pretty much every symbol in ``FE` `` at this point.

Comment: Something that may prove useful: here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756565/creating-robust-real-time-monitors-for-variables) @halirutan discusses using ``Internal`GetTrackedSymbols[] `` and finds the ID numbers that some functions clearly use to get the actual dynamic ID (i.e., the 44 in ``FE`A$44 ``). Unfortunately I can't figure out how to go from those numbers to that serial number, still.

Comment: Every symbol in the ``FE` `` context is a kernel variable used by the front end.  I was thinking of something along the lines of `CurrentValue["DynamicModuleNumber"]` (except such a string token may not exist).  Or a `FrontEndExecute` command.  But maybe no such functionality exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Intro

The answer is: Yes, if you know what you want and it makes sense.

Let's say we want to get current parent's module number from withing `Module`, this is the way to go:

```
Module[{x}, {x, $ModuleNumber -1 }]
```

For `DynamicModule` it does NOT make sense in context of initial evaluation but:

- it makes sense in context of any evaluation triggered from within generated `DynamicModuleBox`, at the end it is the FrontEnd who owns it:

  ```
  DynamicModule[{x}
  , {
      $DynamicModuleNumber                        (* does NOT make sense *)
        , Dynamic @  $DynamicModuleNumber         (* DOES make sense *)
    , Button["run", Print @ $DynamicModuleNumber] (* DOES make sense on click*)
    }
  ]
  ```
- one needs to be aware and EXPECT that if you close/open notebook/cdf containing this `DynamicModuleBox`, it will change.
- you need to EXPECT that if you copy and paste the parent box/cell, it will change
- it may change if you edit an output cell the `DynamicModuleBox` lives in
- for modularized/nested apps with multiple `DynamicModuleBox` instances one needs to know what is going on to stay in control. That is, you can always get the module number in `Initialization` and pass by value to nested elements in the body if they are built from DynamicModules too.

Those limitations enclose a good bunch of use cases anyway so one may wonder why the api to that number is not public/more user friendly.

## Example

```
DynamicModule[{x, y}
, {
    Dynamic @ DynamicModuleNumber[]
  , Dynamic@x
  , Dynamic@y
  , Button["set x", x = DynamicModuleNumber[]]
  , Button["set y", y = DynamicModuleNumber[], Method -> "Queued"]
  }
] (* twice *)
```

[image]

## Code

So, let's cook up something with respect to what makes sense. Your answer already does something like this but it is too cumbersome for me.

```
DynamicModuleNumber::noparent="DynamicMoudelNumber not executed in DynamicModule";
DynamicModuleNumber::nokids="DynamicMoudelNumber can not access any variable of parent DynamicModule";

DynamicModuleNumber[]:= DynamicModuleNumber[FrontEnd`Private`names]
DynamicModuleNumber[HoldPattern[FrontEnd`Private`names]]:=(
  Message[DynamicModuleNumber::noparent];$Failed
);
DynamicModuleNumber[{}]:=(Message[DynamicModuleNumber::nokids];$Failed);
DynamicModuleNumber[{Hold[sym_Symbol],___}]:=First @ StringCases[
  SymbolName[Unevaluated[sym]]
, __~~"$$"~~dmn:DigitCharacter..~~EndOfString:>ToExpression[dmn]
]
```

## Explanation

When FE sends a packet to evaluation, which comes from an object (`Dynamic/Button`) embedded in  `DynamicModuleBox`,  it wraps the packet with `ExecuteInDynamicModule`.

E.g. clicking this button

```
DynamicModule[{},      Button["print", foo[]]    ]
```

will result in `FE --> K`

```
System`EvaluatePacket[ 
  FrontEnd`SynchronousDynamicEvaluate[ 
    FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule[
      {}
    , 89
    , TimeConstrained[
        Function[Global`foo[]][BoxData["\"print\""], Automatic, 1, {}]
      , 6.0
      ]
    ]
  , 0
  , 9.0
  , 383.25714111328125
  ]
]
```

`89` there is the parent's dynamic module number. Fortunately `` FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule `` can be `PrintDefinitions-ed` so we can learn that it does something like:

```
ExecuteInDynamicModule[init_, serialno_, body_] := Block[
    {names, ...},
    ...
    names = Symbol @ StringJoin[
      "FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$", ToString @ serialno
    ];
    ...
    ... body ...
    ...
];
```

It means that **dynamically scoped (Block)** `names` (`` FrontEnd`Private`names ``) will contain information about `serialno`, which turn out to be a list of variables `{Hold[x$$234], ...}`.

Great, assuming there is at least one variable in parent `DynamicModuleBox` we can parse this symbol, which is what the last down value of `DynamicModuleNumber` does.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I’ve been doing/where I got it. But as you note, my solution is a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: @b3m2a1 right, hope you don't mind that slightly excessively explanatory style but my goal was a self contained explanation for future visitors rather than a short piece of code for few :).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: there is no equivalent of `$ModuleNumber` for `DynamicModule`.

Authoritative comments by John Fultz ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116167/internal-dynamicmodule-steals-scope-of-external-dynamicmodule#comment323238_116199) and [below](http://.)) about the scoping of `DynamicModule` and how and why it is differing from the comparably simpler scoping of `Module`:

> [...] "this would require a concept of `$ModuleNumber` to be handled natively
>   by the FE in the typesetting. Which could not be relied upon in the
>   global namespace, so we'd have to be constantly rewriting the
>   typesetting based upon the global state of the FE. Right now, the only
>   concept of `$ModuleNumber` is one attached to the kernel instantiation,
>   which does not require typesetting and can be different in different
>   sessions. I'm not saying that would have been impossible to do this,
>   but implementation would have been quite tricksy."
>
> [...] "the case outlined here is equivalent to something like
>   `Module[{x}, Function[{y}, Module[{x}, {x, y}]][x]]`.
>   Except *in typesetting*. `Module` evaluates away on us after doing its
>   replacement, but `DynamicModuleBox` is a persistent creature, and we
>   must always be able to determine which `DynamicModuleBox` we want
>   each variable to target in order to solve the problem. You have to
>   do that by renaming the variables in the typesetting. If you're not 
>   thinking of this as a typesetting problem, you're not properly 
>   understanding the problem."

Answer (score 2):

So, yes, there's no equivalent, but just as a quick work-around we can leverage our knowledge of how the FE works to extract it. Consider this:

```
DynamicModule[{
  dmlist,
  serialno
  },
 Dynamic@serialno,
 Initialization :>
  (
   serialno =
    Max@
     ToExpression@
       StringTrim[
        Names["FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$*"],
        "FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$"
        ];
   dmlist =
    ToExpression["FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$" <> ToString[serialno]]
   )
 ]
```

That `serialno` is now a handle we can use to access the variables the `DynamicModule` is serializing for us. The `dmlist` is just a fun example of what it's useful for.

I can't remember why I wanted it, but now it's there.

Just for fun here's how it let's us figure out what a `DynamicModule` var is called from the boxes:

```
dynamicModuleSerialNoExtract[box_DynamicModuleBox] :=

  FirstCase[box,
   HoldPattern[_Symbol?(
        Function[Null,
         SymbolName[Unevaluated@#] === "serialno$$",
         HoldAllComplete
         ]) = sn_Integer] :> sn,
   $Failed,
   \[Infinity]
   ];
dynamicModuleSerialNoExtract[e_] :=
  FirstCase[e,
   d_DynamicModuleBox :>
    dynamicModuleSerialNoExtract[d],
   $Failed,
   \[Infinity]
   ];

dynamicModuleVarExtract[varName_String, e_] :=

  Replace[dynamicModuleSerialNoExtract[e],
   i_Integer :> ToExpression@("FE`" <> varName <> "$" <> ToString[i])
   ];
dynamicModuleVarExtract[var_Symbol, e_] :=
  dynamicModuleVarExtract[
   Evaluate@ToString[Unevaluated[var]],
   e
   ];
dynamicModuleVarExtract[a_?(MatchQ[_String | _Symbol]), e_] :=

  dynamicModuleVarExtract[Evaluate@a, e];
dynamicModuleVarExtract~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

It scrapes out this `serialno` and then sticks it onto the var in question.

Then here's a quick wrapper function for this `DynamicModule` form:

```
serializedDynamicModule[{vars___},
   e : Except[_?OptionQ] : Dynamic[serialno],
   ops___?OptionQ] :=
  DynamicModule[{
    serialno,
    vars
    },
   e,
   Initialization :>
    (
     serialno =
       Max@
        ToExpression@
         StringTrim[
          Names["FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$*"],
          "FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$"
          ];
     ),
   ops
   ];
serializedDynamicModule~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
```

And finally here's the thing in action:

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],
 Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@serializedDynamicModule[{}],"Output"]
 ];
dynamicModuleVarExtract[DynamicModuleVariableList,NotebookRead@NextCell[]]

893

{Hold[FE`serialno$$893]}
```

Note that we really shouldn't be able to extract this, so this is something of a win, even if it's largely without application.