# Problem reusing Dynamic variables illustrated by synchronized Panes code

Tags: plotting, dynamic, scoping

Suppose I have several plots that represent different views of a common set of time sequence data but each `Plot` contains too much data (all of which I want available for inspection) to fit nicely within the width of a notebook on my screen. My idea is to scale up each plot to a size that makes it easy to read, put each plot in its own horizontally scrollable `Pane`, stack them up vertically in the notebook, and use a `Dynamic` setting for the `ScrollPosition` of each `Pane` so they are all synched up to display the same data element in the center of each `Pane`.

The code I developed does just this, but it's running into problems when it is invoked more than once in the same notebook. The problem apparently stems from the non-local nature of `DynamicModule` variables. Whereas it is possible to call a `Function` containing a `Module` multiple times without the local variables from different calls ever interacting with each other, this does not seem to be the case where `DynamicModule` variables are concerned.

I have read other MSE posts on the similar topics (e.g., [Internal DynamicModule steals scope of external DynamicModule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116167/73063)) but haven't been able to figure out how to apply the suggestions presented there to my particular case.

My code is shown below in a much simplified form. The essential elements are contained in two functions named `PanedPlot` and `SynchedPlots`. `ScrollablePaneWidth` is just a method for finding a `Pane` width that fits nicely inside a notebook.

```
Clear[PanedPlot]
SetAttributes[PanedPlot, HoldFirst]
PanedPlot[{r_, firstPassQ_, xMax_}, {plot_, paneWidth_}] :=
 DynamicModule[{x},
  Labeled[
   Pane[
    plot, paneWidth, Scrollbars -> {Automatic, False},
    ScrollPosition -> Dynamic[
      If[firstPassQ, {xMax, 0}, {x = xMax r, 0}],
      If[firstPassQ, xMax = First@#, x = First@#; r = x/xMax] &
      ]
    ], {firstPassQ, r, x, xMax} // Dynamic, Top
   ]
  ]
```

A few comments about `PanedPlot`:

The `HoldFirst` attribute for `PanedPlot` causes it to emulate 'pass by reference' functionality for function parameters `r`, `firstPassQ`, and `xMax`.

`firstPassQ` is a control flag. On the first pass, `xMax` gets set to the maximum value of the scroll position (assuming `xMax` started out with a greater value than this). On subsequent passes, the code sets the scroll position from the saved value of `xMax` and the relative scroll position `r`, which is  in turn determined by the position of the present scroll bar or the other scroll bar, whichever one was actively moved. That's how pane position synchronization is maintained. (In my actual code, it's a more complicated relationship, but it follows the same principle.)

```
Clear[SynchedPlots]
SynchedPlots[plotA_, plotB_, paneWidth_] :=
 DynamicModule[{firstPassQ = True, r = 0},
  DynamicModule[{xMaxA = 10^10, xMaxB = 10^10},
    Column[{
       PanedPlot[{r, firstPassQ, xMaxA}, {plotA, paneWidth}],
       PanedPlot[{r, firstPassQ, xMaxB}, {plotB, paneWidth}]
       }] // Dynamic
    ] // Print;
  FinishDynamic[];
  firstPassQ = False;
  ]
```

A few comments about `SynchedPlots`:

On first invocation, `firstPassQ` is set to `True` in the outer `DynamicModule` to tell `PanedPlot` to determine and save the value of `xMax` appropriate to its plot. However, this won't actually happen until each plot has finished displaying, which is the reason for `FinishDynamic` and the nested `DynamicModule`s. The call to `FinishDynamic` guarantees that `xMaxA` and `xMaxB` get updated before `firstPassQ` is set to `False`.

```
Clear[ScrollablePaneWidth]
ScrollablePaneWidth[] :=
 With[{windowWidth = 
    First[WindowSize /. 
      AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]], 
   magnification = 
    Magnification /. 
     AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification], 
   cellMargin = 
    Total@First[
      CellMargins /. AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellMargins]]},
  (windowWidth - 34)/magnification - cellMargin - 20
  ]
```

Any single call to `SynchedPlots` works as designed. For example

```
aspectRatio = .1;
imageSize = 2000;
paneWidth = ScrollablePaneWidth[];
plot =
  Map[Plot[#[[1]][x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
     Background -> #[[3]], AspectRatio -> aspectRatio/#[[2]], 
     ImageSize -> #[[2]] imageSize] &, 
   Transpose@{{Sin, Cos, Csc, Tan}, {1, 1.5, 1.3, 1.8}, {LightYellow, 
      LightOrange, LightGreen, LightBlue}}];
```

followed by

```
SynchedPlots[plot[[1]], plot[[2]], paneWidth];
```

works fine. Here is a snapshot of what the display looks like very close to the middle of the scroll bar range

[image]

However, the next time it is called in the same notebook, such as with

```
SynchedPlots[plot[[3]], plot[[4]], paneWidth];
```

the newest `SynchedPlots` display works until you go back and try to move the scroll bars in the previous one, at which point all the scroll bars freeze up. Re-evaluate either cell and its display will work again as long as you don't touch the other one.

The idea that the problem stems from non-independent dynamic variables is reinforced by what happens when both `SynchedPlots` are evaluated inside a single `Module`, as shown below.

```
Module[{aspectRatio = .1, imageSize = 2000, 
  paneWidth = ScrollablePaneWidth[], plot},
 plot =
  Map[Plot[#[[1]][x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
     Background -> #[[3]], AspectRatio -> aspectRatio/#[[2]], 
     ImageSize -> #[[2]] imageSize] &, 
   Transpose@{{Sin, Cos, Csc, Tan}, {1, 1.5, 1.3, 1.8}, {LightYellow, 
      LightOrange, LightGreen, LightBlue}}];
 {SynchedPlots[plot[[1]], plot[[2]], paneWidth], 
  SynchedPlots[plot[[3]], plot[[4]], paneWidth]}
 ]
```

With only one `SynchedPlots` call, everything is fine. But with two the result looks like

[image]

Right from the start none of the scroll bars work. The plot labels suggest that the dynamic parameters `firstPassQ`, `r`, and `x` are not being evaluated properly (whereas the values of `xMax` are).

What's going wrong and how exactly does one fix it?

It's nice to have this type of functionality available in Mathematica for displaying large data sets. It would be even better if it could be used more than once in a single notebook.

Comment: Each set of `SynchedPlots` would have a different value of `paneWidth` upon evaluation. When you evaluate one, it is fine and `paneWidth` is set, then you evaluate the next one & redefine `paneWidth`, so it is fine now only for the second one you have evaluated. If you try to evaluate two, which should `paneWidth` be valid for? I would say none of them. You should find a different way to use or define `paneWidth`.

Comment: Not so. `paneWidth` is computed once and passed by value. The width setting is the same for each `Pane` by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact that the outermost `DynamicModule` is never really displayed, causing its variables (in particular `firstPassQ`) to be cleared at some point (not sure why it happens exactly when a second one is displayed though). You can see this yourself by putting an `Echo` around the `If[firstPassQ, xMax = …]`, and it will print in an unevaluated state after it breaks.

But you don't need all those tricks with `firstPassQ` etc. anyway: For your case, you don't need to synchronize the initialization at all: Every instance of `PanedPlot` can simply initialize its own `xMax`, and then use `r` to communicate with the other plots. Here's how I'd implement it:

```
Clear[PanedPlot]
SetAttributes[PanedPlot, HoldFirst]
PanedPlot[r_, {plot_, paneWidth_}] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {x, init = False, xMax = 10^10},
  Labeled[
   Pane[
    plot, paneWidth,
    Scrollbars -> {Automatic, False},
    ScrollPosition -> Dynamic[
      If[! init, {xMax, 0}, {x = xMax r, 0}],
      If[! init && First@# > 0, init = True; xMax = First@#, 
        x = First@#; r = x/xMax] &]
    ],
   {init, r, x, xMax} // Dynamic,
   Top
   ]
  ]

Clear[SynchedPlots]
SynchedPlots[plotA_, plotB_, paneWidth_] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {r = 0},
  Column[
    {PanedPlot[r, {plotA, paneWidth}], 
     PanedPlot[r, {plotB, paneWidth}]}
    ] // Dynamic
  ]


Clear[ScrollablePaneWidth]
ScrollablePaneWidth[] := 
 With[{windowWidth = 
    First[WindowSize /. 
      AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]], 
   magnification = 
    Magnification /. 
     AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification], 
   cellMargin = 
    Total@First[
      CellMargins /. AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellMargins]]},
   (windowWidth - 34)/magnification - cellMargin - 20
  ]


aspectRatio = .1;
imageSize = 2000;
paneWidth = ScrollablePaneWidth[];
plot = Map[
   Plot[#[[1]][x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
     Background -> #[[3]], AspectRatio -> aspectRatio/#[[2]], 
     ImageSize -> #[[2]] imageSize] &, 
   Transpose@{{Sin, Cos, Csc, Tan}, {1, 1.5, 1.3, 1.8}, {LightYellow, 
      LightOrange, LightGreen, LightBlue}}];

SynchedPlots[plot[[1]], plot[[2]], paneWidth]
```

Comment: Shorter than the original code and works better. Excellent answer. I hadn't known about the `Echo` command before. Very helpful for debugging `Dynamic` code. Adding `Echo` in several places inside the `ScrollPosition` calculation showed how much the order of operations differed from my expectations. Very much appreciated.