# How does the Kernel know the $Context in a localized notebook

Tags: front-end, kernel, system

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]

$Context
```

> ```
> "Notebook$$70$398424`"
> ```

And from different notebook it will be

> ```
> "Global`"
> ```

I suppose the kernel can match a proper context to a given NotebookObject but how it is done if such information isn't sent to the Kernel?

Here is what the LinkSnooper says:

> FE ---> K: `EnterExpressionPacket[MakeExpression[BoxData["$Context"], StandardForm]]`
>
> FE <--- K: `OutputNamePacket["Out[1]= "]`
>
> FE <--- K: `` ReturnExpressionPacket[BoxData["\"Notebook$$70$398424`\"", StandardForm]] ``

So the Kernel knows what to answer even though it was just asked about the `$Context`.

[Installing LinkSnooper on Windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66465/5478)

Comment: When did you start tracking the packets? Did you capture the traffic when you set the Notebook context to unique?

Comment: @rcollyer I assumed it does not matter because traffic from all notebooks is going though the same link, and there is no info in those Packets about where they come from. So K and FE are talking behind our backs or LinkSnooper does not show everything. Or I missed something basic.

Comment: @Kuba there is a utility function that gets called whenever the FrontEnd deems that the `$Context` needs to be updated.  It will not appear in the output as `Set[$Context, ...]`.

Comment: @ihojnicki and rcollyer ah it is there, I missed that because I was playing with Snooper for selected notebooks while I should have set `$FrontEndSession's` `Evaluator`. Unless someone is willing to authoritatively answer I will do that later.

Comment: The function @ihojnicki is talking about seems to be: ``FrontEnd`Private`SwitchCellContext``, as you can run ``FrontEnd`Private`SwitchCellContextEvaluate["asd`", ToExpression@"zzz"]`` to run stuff in that new context. This seems to be like the case of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108850/what-is-the-equivalent-of-modulenumber-for-dynamicmodule

Answer (score 2):

You can see what is going on by setting `$FrontEndSession` `Evaluator->"LinkSnooper"`.

- Create a notebook (A) with two cells and evaluate them:

  ```
  SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Evaluator -> "LinkSnooper"]
  ```

  ```
  $Context
  ```
- Create another (B) one with:

  ```
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]
  ```

  ```
  $Context
  ```

Let's clear LinkSnooper's console and check what happens when we evaluate `$Context` in (A) and (B). Here is an output (reduced to a relevant part, also FE/Kernel communication expressions names have "*Paclet" pattern (e.g. `EvaluatePaclet`), I dropped `Paclet` for a readability)

```
 $Context
```

> ```
> "Global`"
> ```

FE -> K: `` Evaluate[FrontEnd`Private`SwitchCellContext["Global`", "Main"]] ``

FE <- K: `` Return["Notebook$$18$756624`"] ``

FE -> K: `` Evaluate[ToExpression["FE`SetEvaluationNotebookFileName[None];"]] ``

FE -> K: `EnterExpression[MakeExpression[BoxData["$Context"], StandardForm]]`

FE <- K: `` ReturnExpression[BoxData["\"Global`\"", StandardForm]] ``

```
$Context
```

> ```
> "Notebook$$18$756624`"
> ```

FE -> K: `` Evaluate[FrontEnd`Private`SwitchCellContext["Notebook$$18$756624`", "Main"]] ``

FE <- K: `` Return["Global`"] ``

FE -> K: `` Evaluate[ToExpression["FE`SetEvaluationNotebookFileName[None];"]] ``

FE -> K: `EnterExpression[MakeExpression[BoxData["$Context"], StandardForm]]`

FE <- K: `` ReturnExpression[BoxData["\"Notebook$$18$756624`\"", StandardForm]] ``

Repeating last evaluation shows no sign of `SwitchCellContext`, which probably means that the FrontEnd knows from where the last input was read and in case of change it asks the Kernel to `SwitchCellContext[ to-notebookCellContex, on-kernel]`.

Which is just a quck guess from a short test. Any insight is appreciated, edit or answer if you want to add someyhing.