# Get context from notebook

Tags: notebooks, contexts, palettes

The function [`Context[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Context.html) returns the context of the Notebook the function is called in.

**Is there a function where we can specify *e.g* a Notebook object and retrieve the context from that file?**

I'm creating a palette where I want to change a variable located in a Notebook that has the context local to that notebook. From the palette I would like to use [`SelectedNotebook[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectedNotebook.html) and retrieve the context.

Thx for advise!

Comment: Can you give a tiny example of such a palette, to get a better idea of what you need?  What if the context is unique to cell groups instead of notebooks? How does the palette obtain the variable name?

Comment: Also, `Context[]` does not need to be notebook's `CellContext`, e.g. if `Begin/BeginPackage` was used.

Comment: related: [How does the Kernel know the $Context in a localized notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120621/5478)

Comment: I guess a more concrete question would be: How do we evaluate code as if it were entered at the current cursor position in the notebook?

Comment: I would like to have multiple notebooks with private context. All these notebook wil have a variable "data". with the Palette I would like to modify the values (email, phone, names etc) contained in data with a PaletteNotebook combined with inputfields etc. Using Dynamic[data] will show the change and the Palette will also write the results to a file

Comment: @Szabolcs it is possible to do that when I "know" the context (eg I give it the name of the notebookfile) but perhaps more error prone.

Comment: Do you really need a palette? Would a function (loaded from a package) work instead? How about a palette that writes `myFunction[data]` into the notebook (perhaps along with a `Needs`)?  Maybe automatically insert that as an input cell, then evaluate it. Maybe even delete it after evaluation, if that's what you prefer.

Comment: @Szabolcs That is a valid alternative and easier to implement. So basically the Notebooks have standard a Needs (to package with function) in the evaluation Cell and then just shoot in a cell and evaluate it there and remove the original input cell (so the output cell has the formatted Grid etc).  It also might be a safer alternative with multiple NB's  open.