# Current $Context of a given notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks, contexts, system

```
nb = CreateDocument[{Dynamic@$Context}, CellContext -> Notebook]
```

It will show `` Notebook$$22$93500` `` or something similar. How to get this context value without interfering with `nb` too much? You should also assume we do not control `nb` generation.

Unfortunately

```
AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, CellContext]
```

> Notebook

FrontEnd knows it: [How does the Kernel know the $Context in a localized notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120621/5478), the question is if user can access it.

Comment: You want the notebook context when the notebook does not have `CellContext -> Notebook` set in its preferences?

Comment: @Edmund for any case except `CellGroup/Cell` because then it does not make sense. But we can say: "what is the context in `First@Cells[nb]`. Then this makes sense for every scenario

Comment: @Kuba this is something I’ve tried to figure out many times and I still have no idea how. The “switch context” functions in the ``"FE`"`` context get called when you evaluate anything in the notebook but I don’t know where the context gets pulled from.

Comment: @Kuba, the FE does not provide a mechanism to query for what that value might be.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thanks for feedback. Somehow I was not notified about your comment.